# to position center in a view / position:absolute &?

Tags: css, css-position

I used to use

```
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

but i saw ppl also use

```
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
```

I know both working in same way, but i'd like to know which one is more efficient or more appropriate way for web standard.

Comment: Either is fine; it depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve, and the code you are working with.

Comment: In the second way the container could stretch from the top to the bottom if it doesn't have an absolute max-height or height property.